# PHP function to count business days adds a day to much

Tags: php, function, date

I have this `PHP` `function`:

```
function calculateNextDate($startDate, $days)
{
    $dateTime = new DateTime($startDate);

        while($days) {
            $dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));    

            if ($dateTime->format('N') < 6) {
                $days--;
            }
        }

    return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

It calculates what date it will be from a startdate given a number of days, and skips weekends.

If i echo this:

```
echo calculateNextDate('2012-10-01', '10');
```

It will print:

```
2012-10-15
```

Which is wrong... `2012-10-01` + 10 business days is `2012-10-12`

Any idea on why it adds another day?

Comment: 2012-10-15 looks right to me? 2012-10-12 would be the 9th business day.

Answer (score 3):

My kind sir, 1 + 10 = 11, not 10.

Therefore, if you ask to add 10 days to october 1st with your algorithm, it doesn't give the friday 12, it really gives out monday 15...

You want friday? Then it's 9 days...

Comment: Oh, my bad. Is there any way to make my `function` count the startday as 1 day?

Comment: Remove 1 from the total number of days to move? Why change the algorithm if it's already working? Just remove 1 day from the total days to move. But technicaly, the problem is the understanding how to use the function correctly. And 1 day ahead of today is not today, it's tomorrow